# WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips not working in Chinese

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips booster plugin  it offers font family like Chinese or  droidsansfall back. Anyway, it should work on Chinese but it does not. As long as your invoice has Chinese, then it will disappear....

Does anyone know how to make invoice acceptable as Chinese?

Comment: You should better ask WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips plugin support… StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create custom template](http://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/creating-a-custom-pdf-template/)
2. Download [微軟正黑體](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-tw/download/details.aspx?id=12072)
3. Extract msjh.ttf and msjhbd.ttf from the .exe by e.g. 7-zip to the fonts folder in custom template location
4. Add the below PHP code to functions.php
5. Go to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpo_wcpdf_options_page and select your custom template in Choose a template

The Chinese text should now be rendered properly.

```php
<?php

add_action('wpo_wcpdf_custom_styles', function($type, $pdf) {
    $template_path = $pdf->get_template_path();
    $css = <<<CSS
/*
「微軟正黑體」字型檔（msjh.ttf）官方正版下載說明
http://prompt.nou.edu.tw/utf8_web/sno475/content/qa/guideWebPages/FontsMsjh_DownloadAndInstallationGuide.html
https://www.microsoft.com/zh-tw/download/details.aspx?id=12072
*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjh.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjhbd.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjh.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjhbd.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.address,
.shop-name h3,
.item-name {
    font-family: 'msjh';
}
CSS;
    echo $css;
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Wong thanks it worked

```
<?php

add_action('wpo_wcpdf_custom_styles', function($type, $pdf) {
    $template_path = $pdf->get_template_path();
    $css = <<<CSS
/*
「微軟正黑體」字型檔（msjh.ttf）官方正版下載說明
http://prompt.nou.edu.tw/utf8_web/sno475/content/qa/guideWebPages/FontsMsjh_DownloadAndInstallationGuide.html
https://www.microsoft.com/zh-tw/download/details.aspx?id=12072
*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjh.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjhbd.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjh.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'msjh';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url($template_path/fonts/msjhbd.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.address,
.shop-name h3,
.item-name {
    font-family: 'msjh';
}
CSS;
    echo $css;
}, 10, 2);
```